# iOS8 new .hash property reliable?

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, uitouch, skspritenode, touchesmoved

iOS8 introduced .hash as a read only property.  I've been experimenting with UITouch objects.   It appears each one is assigned a unique hash number, i.e.: 342052784, 342054336, 350766656, 350145296, 350133472.

**Is it reliable to use .hash as an identity tag for UITouch objects?**

I'm building a custom scrollview in SpriteKit, with tap-able sprites in it.
I need to identify which touches have 'moved' vs. those that have just 'ended' without movement in a SKNode.  Gesture recognizers and UIScrollViews won't work for this application.

Comment: I think the default implementation of `hash` just returns the pointer to the receiver cast to a `NSUInteger`.

Comment: Also, `hash` has been around for a long time, it was simply "converted" to a property for iOS 8.